# What is the connection between a function and its second derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been studying calculus for a while and yet there are so many stupid questions that are bugging me.

I know that the derivative of the function $F(x)$, that is $F'(x)$, let us know the rate of change of $F(x)$ and the derivative of $F'(x)$, that is $F''(x)$, let us know the rate of change of $ F'(x)$. Then what is the relationship between $F''(x)$ and $F(x)$ and what's the meaning of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's exactly that - $F''(x)$ tells us how fast $F'(x)$ is changing.

One way of thinking about it is that $F''(x)$ tells us *the rate of change* of *the rate of change* of $F(x)$. In more formal terms, $F''(x)$ tells us the curvature of the function (you probably already heard about the terms "convexity", "concavity" and "an inflection point").

So, if variable $x$ is changing, $F''(x)$ tells us if that changing is slowing down or speeding up. Think about the function $F(x) = x^2$. The second derivative tells us that as we are coming to the vertex of the parabola from the left, the rate of change is coming to a halt.

You can think about it through the lens of physics. Let the variable $s$ be the distance a car travelled. The speed at which this $s$ changes is the car's velocity: $v = s'$

But a car can also accelerate. This means that its speed is changing: $a = v' = s''$

Answer (score 1):

It tells you the curvature around that point. If it is positive, it is locally facing "upwards" (think of $x^2$), otherwise if negative "downwards" and if $0$ it is flat. It tells you also about the convexity or concavity of the function.